# How to set Visitor Name OR ID Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

How to set Visitor Name OR ID using gtag and display it on Google Analytics with page hit

I have tried this but it didn't give the visitor.

```
  gtag('config', 'My_key', {
    'page_title': title,
    'page_path': window.location.pathname,
    'user_id': visitor
});
```

for example:-

| UserID | Page Title |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | home/index |
| user2 | home/other |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a **User-ID View** to see that value (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123669), or if you want to see that information in your normal View you have to pass it as **custom dimension**.